# R gridExtra 2.0.0: tableGrob vertical and horizontal padding

Tags: r, gridextra

I want to know how to do in gridExtra 2.0.0 what I could do in previous versions to change table width/height padding e.g.:

```
grid.arrange(tableGrob(mtcars,padding.h=unit(1,"mm"),padding.v=unit(1,"mm")))
```

(Sorry I couldn't test the code above because I don't have the older version of gridExtra installed)

I don't want to shrink the text, just want to tighten everything together so the table fits where I'm putting it on a PDF page.

I can see the "widths" property has **"+4mm"** on every entry, but I don't know how to change those to, say, **+2mm**.

Of course I would prefer if there was a simple `"padding"` property I could change.

My question is in a similar vein as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31796219/grid-table-and-tablegrob-in-gridextra-package).

Comment: the padding is defined in the theme, see `ttheme_default`

Answer (score 7):

You have to use a *theme*, and as *baptiste* comments, you can use ttheme_default to show the properties of the default theme.

```
ttheme_default()
```

To set the padding of the table "core" to 1 mm:

```
mytheme <- gridExtra::ttheme_default(
             core = list(padding=unit(c(1, 1), "mm"))
           )
mytable <- tableGrob(mtcars, theme = mytheme)
```