# tableGrob: resizing a table (changing font size) drawn on top of ggplot using annotation_custom

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, gridextra

I'm having some issues resizing the text in a table drawn over a plot using tableGrob() and annotation_custom(). Essentially, I want the font size in the table to be smaller so that the overall table is smaller. I've checked the [tableGrob() documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gridExtra/versions/0.9.1/topics/tableGrob) and have followed it to the best of my ability, but I must be doing something wrong as it's throwing an error.

Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

df <- data.frame(x=seq(1,10),y=seq(11,20))
table <- data.frame(x=seq(1,3),y=seq(4,6))

ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point() +
 annotation_custom(tableGrob(table,rows=NULL),xmin=0,xmax=3,ymin=15,ymax=20) # plot drawn successfully without text resizing

ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point() + 
  annotation_custom(tableGrob(table,rows=NULL,gpar.coretext = gpar(col = "black", cex = 0.8)),xmin=0,xmax=3,ymin=15,ymax=20)
 # error when attempting to resize text following tableGrob documentation
```

This is the error I get when I run the second ggplot() command:

```
Error in gtable_table(d, name = "core", fg_fun = theme$core$fg_fun, bg_fun = theme$core$bg_fun,  : 
  unused argument (gpar.coretext = list(col = "black", cex = 0.8))
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to adjust the Font Size of tableGrob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31776557/how-to-adjust-the-font-size-of-tablegrob)

Comment: I think the problem with the documentation is that's a link the the documentation for the old version of the package `0.9.1` and the current version is `2.3.0` and that help page is here: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gridExtra/versions/2.3/topics/tableGrob. New versions prefer to use themes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want *all* the text to be smaller in your table, use `base_size` in `ttheme_default`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

df <- data.frame(x=seq(1,10),y=seq(11,20))
table <- data.frame(x=seq(1,3),y=seq(4,6))

ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  annotation_custom(tableGrob(table,rows=NULL, theme = ttheme_default(base_size = 8)),
                    xmin=0,xmax=3,ymin=15,ymax=20)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks so much, this works! Turns out I was looking at an old version of the documentation. Really appreciate the response.