# Printing out a dataframe in R: grid.table outputs cropped tables, doesn't respond to fontsize

Tags: r, pdf, gridextra

I am trying to automate a series of analyses which are intended to save a number of plots for later inspection. One of the plots will be accompanied by a table of values. I'd like to have them in the same pdf so that the users don't have to jump between files.

I have checked numerous questions on SO regarding outputting data frames to pdf, here are a couple of reasons why existing answers aren't satisfactory in my case:

- Not familiar with knitr/Sweave
- Batch generation of figures mean that I cannot do it manually via RStudio Viewer
- grid.table based solutions do not generate the entire table.

Which brings me to my problems, say I have a table 48 x 5 in proportions. If I try to plot it out with `grid.table(geno)`  it results in a cropped table showing some 20-30 rows in the middle. If I go with `grid.table(geno, gp = gpar(fontsize=8))` to decrease the fontsize I get the following error message.

```
Error in gtable_table(d, name = "core", fg_fun = theme$core$fg_fun, bg_fun = theme$core$bg_fun,  : 
  unused argument (gp = list(fontsize = 8)
```

)

Essentially I would like to be able to use it in this way:

```
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
pdf(file="gtype.pdf", title = "Genotype data")
plotGenotype(geno, text_size = 10)    # outputs a custom plot
grid.newpage()
grid.table(geno)         # grid.table(geno, gp = gpar(fontsize=8))
dev.off()
```

The problem here is that I either get a cropped table or nothing at all, on the second page. I noticed that many people add `height=11, width=8.5` to the `pdf()` call. I am not sure if/why that would make a difference but setting `paper="a4"` or height/width according to A4 does not make any difference in my case.

**Q1:** Is it not possible to get `grid.table` to resize based on content and not paper?

**Q2:** Is there some other way to get a data frame printed to a pdf without having to go through LaTeX based solutions?

(I am currently running R 3.3.1 and gridExtra 2.2.1)

Comment: have you checked [this FAQ](https://github.com/baptiste/gridextra/wiki#problems-with-gridtable)?

Comment: @baptiste thanks for the link. I have seen the examples/documentation but must have missed the FAQ somehow. I have ask though, where in [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31620903/328725) does the fontsize gets adjusted?

Comment: font size is set in the theme, that's 7pts in `ttheme_default(7)`

Comment: @baptiste thanks :)

Comment: for what it's worth, i'd strongly suggest moving toward a LaTeX solution/workflow; grid.table is intrinsically a very limited approach, and should typically be used for very basic (and small) tables.

Answer (score 2):

**Q1**: *Is it not possible to get grid.table to resize based on content and not paper?*

It is possible, but generally not desirable. A table is meant to be read, and if text and spacings were determined by the page rather than the content, it would often yield unreadable results. Thus the usual advice: [manually tweak the font size and padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22138111/how-do-i-fit-a-very-wide-grid-table-or-tablegrob-to-fit-on-a-pdf-page/31620903#31620903), or [split the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937131/print-to-pdf-file-using-grid-table-in-r-too-many-rows-to-fit-on-one-page/31767682#31767682).

It is by no means a technical limitation: feel free to [set the cell size to fit the page](https://github.com/baptiste/gridextra/wiki/tableGrob#further-gtable-processing-and-integration):

```
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(width=unit(0.8,"npc"), height=unit(0.8,"npc")))
g <- g2 <- tableGrob(iris[1:4, 1:3], cols = NULL, rows=NULL)
g2$heights <- unit(rep(1/nrow(g2), nrow(g2)), "npc")
grid.arrange(rectGrob(), rectGrob(), nrow=1, newpage = FALSE)
grid.arrange(g, g2, nrow=1, newpage = FALSE)
```

[image]

but with too much content for the page it's unclear what result is better

```
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(width=unit(0.8,"npc"), height=unit(0.8,"npc")))

g <- g2 <- tableGrob(iris[1:20, 1:3], cols = NULL, rows=NULL)
g3 <- tableGrob(iris[1:20, 1:3], cols = NULL, rows=NULL, theme=ttheme_default(base_size=7))
g2$heights <- g3$heights <- unit(rep(1/nrow(g2), nrow(g2)), "npc")
grid.arrange(rectGrob(), rectGrob(), rectGrob(), nrow=1, newpage = FALSE)
grid.arrange(g, g2, g3, nrow=1, newpage = FALSE)
```

[image]

If the page size can be changed, it is usually the best option. One can query the table size before drawing, convert it to inches, and pass it to the device.

```
g1 <- tableGrob(iris[1:4, 1:5])
g2 <- tableGrob(iris[1:20, 1:5])

maxheight <- convertHeight(sum(g2$heights), "in", TRUE)
pdf("fit.pdf", height=maxheight)
grid.draw(g1)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g2)
dev.off()
```

[image]

However, as far as I know all pages in a given pdf will have to have the same size (there might be ways around it, but tricky).

Comment: I see your point regarding the readability. Just for the record, I never suggested that the paper size should dictate the table sizing, on the contrary I fully agree that the content size should determine the size of table components. As I mentioned on the comment above, regarding the FAQ, I am not sure how the font-size is tweaked in the example you have given