# How to plot a large table (50 columns) on a pdf?

Tags: r

When I print the tablegrob, only a small viewport on it as shown below.
[image: sample_output]

I have used the following script to print the table to a pdf

```r
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)

mySummaryOfMyData <- summary(someDataframe)
grid.newpage()
mytt1 <- ttheme_default(base_size = 4, base_colour = "blue")
psummary <- gridExtra::tableGrob(as.matrix(mySummaryOfMyData), theme=mytt1)
grid.draw(psummary)
```

How can I show the unclipped data on the full PDF estate?

Comment: You could try something with Rmarkdown using PDF output. You will need some form of latex installed and then you can use the `kable()` function with `format = "latex"`. There are several other arguments you can use to customize the table

Comment: See [How do I fit a very wide grid.table or tableGrob to fit on a pdf page?
Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22138111/how-do-i-fit-a-very-wide-grid-table-or-tablegrob-to-fit-on-a-pdf-page). A couple of alternatives are proposed, and one of them will probably work for you.

Comment: Yes, I also thought of Rmarkdown but wanted to have it with pdf, so I'll try the arrangeGrob with the viewport. Thx